# How to use OneHotEncoder output in ordinary least squares regression plot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scikit-learn, regression

I have been trying to perform Ordinary Least Squares regression using the scikit-learn library but have hit another rock.

I have used OneHotEncoder to binarize my (independent) dummy/categorical features and I have an array like so:

```
x = [[ 1.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
     [ 1.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
     [ 0.  1.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
     ..., 
     [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
     [ 0.  0.  1. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
     [ 1.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]]
```

The dependent variables (Y) are stored in a one dimensional array. Everything is wonderful, except now when I come to plot these values I get an error:

```
# Plot outputs
pl.scatter(x_test, y_test, color='black')
```

**`ValueError: x and y must be the same size`**

When I use numpy.size on X and Y respectively it is clear thats a reasonable error:

```
>>> print np.size(x)
5096
>>> print np.size(y)
98
```

Interestingly, the two sets of data are accepted by the fit method.

**My question is how can I transform the output of OneHotEncoder to use in my regression?**

Comment: You'd need an `x_test.shape[1] + y_test.shape[1]`-dimensional scatterplot to visualize your data ... I don't think that's going to happen. If `y` is also categorical, try visualizing with something along the lines of `mosaicplot` from `R`. I don't see how not being able to scatterplot your data stops you from doing regression on it though.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. Still stuck with this. As each of the sublists in the x array is meant to represent one feature - could I use some kind of dummy variables for x? Just not sure how I could get the coefficients to map onto new variables and use them in the plot. Any ideas? Also yes, you are correct, the regression does work of course - I meant to say "to use in my plot". Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you have your X matrix as an input as an [m x n] matrix and some output Y of [n x 1], where m = number of features and n = number of data points.

Firstly, the linear regression fitting function will not care that X is of dimension [m x n] and Y of [n x 1] as it will simply use a parameter of dimension [1 x m], i.e.,

```
Y = theta * X
```

Unfortunately, as noted by eickenberg, you cannot plot all of the X features against the Y value using matplotlibs scatter call as you have, hence you get the error message of incompatible sizes, it wants to plot n x n not (n x m) x n.

To fix your problem, try looking at a single feature at a time:

```
pl.scatter(x_test[:,0], y_test, color='black')
```

Assuming you have standardised your data (subtracted the mean and divided by the average) a quick and dirty way to see the trends would be plot all of them on a single axes:

```
fig = plt.figure(0)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

n, m = x_test.size
for i in range(m):
   ax.scatter(x_test[:,m], y_test)

plt.show()
```

To visualise all at once on independent figures (depending on the number of features) then look at, e.g., subplot2grid routines or another python module like pandas.